# how to handle images when flex direction is set to column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working with flex layouts and images. My goal is to stack the flex-items on top of each other on smaller screen widths, by setting `flex-direction:  column;` but there is a strange behavior i can't understand. The flex item that wraps the image seems to take the full width of the image. I have created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/adam400/pen/yLbxjeR) that illustrates the problem. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Let the width of the flex item be dictated by the flex container, then size the image to the size of the flex item.**

When you set up a `flex-direction: column` flex container, the height of your flex items is controlled by the `flex` properties (grow, shrink, basis).

The width of a flex item in a `flex-direction: column` flex container can either be dictated by the flex container, or it can be left to the flex item to “decide” how big it wants to be.

In this case `align-items: start` controls the width of your flex items. `start` means that the items can size themselves however they want, and they will be positioned at the *start side* of your flex container.

The flex item that wraps your image doesn’t have its own size (it has the default `width: auto`), so your image’s `width: 100%` can’t be resolved. In that case the image behaves as though it had `width: auto`, and basically renders at its full size. Then, the flex item takes on that size, and that’s why it’s so big in your flex container.

You can force all your flex items to be the width of your column flex container by not setting `align-items` and letting it use the default `normal` value, with stretches the flex items to the width of the flex container. Then your flex items have a specific size, and your image’s `width: 100%` can be resolved against that size.

Here’s a working example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  background-color: #ff1b68;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.item--2 {
  height: 200px;
}

.item--3 {
}

.item--3 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item--1">1</div>
  <div class="item item--2">2</div>
  <div class="item item--3">
    <img
      src="https://images7.alphacoders.com/462/thumb-1920-462576.jpg"
      alt=""
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

By default, each flex item has `align-self: auto`, which means it will look at the flex container’s `align-items` value. So you set `align-items` once, and all flex items use that. But you can specify different `align-self` for each item, if you want to, for example, keep your text flex items `align-self: start`, and your image flex item `align-self: stretch`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a calculated width on your image element setting it to ***view width*** units => `width: calc(100vw - padding - margin)`.  So your image element will be 100% of the view width minus the padding and margin of the it and its parent element. Also set your container to `min-width: 1000px;`.

If the following is not what you are looking for, please let me know.

Resize the browser to test dynamic resizing of image to fit within viewable screen

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background-color: #ff1b68;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  /*flex-grow: 1;*/
}

.item--2 {
  height: 200px;
}

.item--3 {
  order: 1;
}

.item--3 img {
  width: calc(100vw - 130px); 
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item--1">1</div>
  <div class="item item--2">2</div>
  <div class="item item--3">
    <img src="https://images7.alphacoders.com/462/thumb-1920-462576.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet, what i am trying to understand is how does `flex-direction: column;`  work with widths, and heights of the flex-items. Especially a flex-item that contains an image.

Comment: Well if you use a calculated width to accommodate things like margin and padding with VW as a unit of measurement, then it does not matter if the element is flex or not, that will grow or shrink to fit the view port it is being viewed on. Flex does have `flex-basis` which will allow you to set the size of the content box unless otherwise set with `box-sizing`. You can also use `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` or the short hand `flex` to also affect how a `flex` item will *grow* or *shrink* to fit the space available in its *flex container*.